# How realistic is an underwater farm in a glass dome?

Tags: flora, agriculture

Say that hypothetically, I wish to grow plants under the ocean.  I construct a large glass dome and house the plants in a greenhouse contained in that done.  How deep underwater could I plausibly have this dome before, before sunlight wouldn't reach it anymore?  Could a series of farms based on this design be efficient and/or profitable?

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's a nice question, but I'm sure this isn't too hard to find yourself. Light values per depth and what grows are in abundance if I don't mistake my guess. Could you let us know what research you've done yourself?

Comment: Don't forget to take a [tour] and check out the [helpcenter]: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour
  [2]: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: What you are trying to achieve hypothetically, is already a reality. It is currently not on the production level but the basic idea is out there. check this link for video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g9uQcbR-CC0&ab_channel=TechInsider

Comment: Which problem do u try to solve here?

Comment: Answers are stating the problem of there being no light at the bottom of the ocean. But there is yet another problem: Pressure. if depth is too much, your glass dome will just be unable to bear the pressure

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Not so good.

[Seawater attenuates light rather rapidly](https://www.britannica.com/science/seawater/Optical-properties), reducing the merit a great deal.
In the clearest ocean waters only about 1 percent of the surface radiation remains at a depth of 150 metres. And most of *that* is blue-green light, exactly the wavelength of light that plants do not use.

As a hemispherical dome will be at least as deep as its height, the use of "large domes" strongly implies that the dome is situated in significantly deep water (more than 50m or so), and thus would lose access to virtually all beneficial light from the sun.

You might have some success with very shallow (< 10 m) deep smaller greenhouses, but then they are both visible and subject to the vagaries of weather and tides, voiding any benefit of putting them underwater. Might as well make floating surface installations then.

Obviously, if you provide artificial light the scenario is completely different, and depth is only relevant due to pressure.
But then, with domes and artificial light, you might as well be on the ground, under the ground, in the ocean, or even in space.

Comment: Idea: the dome is very large and it uses its glassy surface to focus light on the plants. The farm itself would obviously be much smaller than the base of the dome then. Would this be economical? Hell no. Cool for a story? Oh yeah!

Comment: Except focusing more light that isn't the right wavelengths does nothing.

Comment: @vilx if anything the convex high-to-low density transition will DE-focus incoming light.

Comment: I've forgotten my optics... wasn't the focal point halfway to the centre of the sphere?

Comment: Wrong light colour - well, yeah... but it's still something... maybe you can mess with the light some more to adjust it somehow. Worst case scenario, photovoltaic cells and artificial light.

Comment: Not entirely true.  If the base of the dome is at 150 m, and the radius of the dome is 150 m, then the peak will be at the surface, getting full sunlight.  You might also consider partial sphere domes, perhaps on a cylindrical base, so to have more light penetration.

Answer (score 7):

It might be possible, the intensity of the light decreases the deeper you go in the water, more so for red light than blue light, see image below, which is from [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/304360662_Single_underwater_image_restoration_by_blue-green_channels_dehazing_and_red_channel_correction).[image]

so After a few meters most of the red-yellow light is gone, so the plants would have to use green-blue light, now as PcMan points out most plants don't adsorb green light well/at all. But one of the forms of chlorophyll ([chlorophyll b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorophyll_b)) does adsorb blue light.

[image]

There are also compounds that help broaden the colours of light a plant can adsorb, called [Phycobiliprotein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phycobiliprotein).

Plants can grow using just [blue light](https://gpnmag.com/article/effects-of-blue-light-on-plants/), but they tend to grow shorter.

[image]

Additionally some deep sea plants can grow at depths greater than 30m, some sea grasses have been found at [~$70m$ deep](https://sciencing.com/deep-ocean-plants-13427770.html).

So assuming that there is enough light at ~$20m$ deep for food crops to realistically grow, then assuming that you have a field ~$50m^2$ and need ~$2m$ of height then you'd need a dome of radius ~$35-36m$. which would mean that the base of the dome is at a depth of $55m$ ($20+35$).

As to if it is economical/profitable, I'd doubt it as the cost of constructing a dome of those proportions at that depth would be astronomical compared to the profit you would get from the crops.

hopefully that helps

Answer (score 2):

### This is a really bad plan

Not because it's inherently impossible, there are simply better alternatives. That will potentially be orders of magnitude more efficient. If you still want to go for this, you are likely limited to a few or tens of meters of water at best. The photic zone (where oceans are most productive due to the energy from the sun) ends at a depth of 200 m. No light gets beyond. Note that red and infrared light gets absorbed really fast, while green and blue do get deeper.

As for better alternatives, you might want to try these.

### Aquaculture

This is a rising industry and will become very relevant in the 21st century. Fish in cages, shellfish (which is extremely efficient in respect to food) and alge (which has the potential to become a basic industrial feedstock, as a lot of stuff can be made from the already extremely diverse set of species and genetic engineering (given the Luddites don't ban it) will only increase the number of options).
Espacialy the deep ocean, where the photic zone never reaches the seafloor, could be turned from a region as productive as deserts into aquaculture production centers.

### Off-Shore Hydroponics

Hydroponics are much more productive than traditional farms or greenhouses. Leavy greens and a number of vegetables can be grown at a profit in such a facility where all the environmental factors are optimised. Staple crops are a bit more difficult.
The reason why one would do this out at sea is presumably that one seeks to cover the facilities energy and freshwater needs in an eco friendly manner by using [Ocean Thermal Energy Conversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocean_thermal_energy_conversion). While power can be produced in an eco-friendly manner on land (nuclear, wind, solar), freshwater can be tricky. Desalination plants tend to mess with the local ecology by releasing high salinity brime back into the ocean.

So, ultimately under water greenhouses may look nice in Minecraft, but are utterly impractical in reality.

Answer (score 1):

The economics still won't pencil out, but if you really want to have an underwater area illuminated by sunlight, you'll need something like a solatube -- which is normally a tube that protrudes like a skylight from your ceiling through your roof. In this case, you'd need a sealed column that extends above the ocean surface that collects and reflects the light downward. Think of it like a giant periscope. (You'll also need some method for the column and the dome to resist the increasing water pressure, which is why it needs to be sealed at the top or your straw-like structure will implode.)

This column could also contain your access shaft and maybe support something like a wind-energy system to provide some power to your facility.

Comment: The skylight doesn't need to be air-filled. It could be e.g. a giant fiber-optic-bundle or another form of light guide. This removes much of technical issues but the cost is still great.